# Comentário automático sem tradução

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização, comentários

O comentário automático de comentários movidos para o chat está em inglês. Esse é um comentário postado pelo sistema quando um moderador, a partir de uma sinalização automática de excesso de comentários, move todos os comentários para o chat (é um recurso relativamente novo no sistema):

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have configured this text for translation and it will be correctly translated in the near future by our batch translation process. Sorry for the delay and inconvenience.